# Cannot paste into an SMA runbook

Tags: automation

I'm attempting to paste content into a draft version of a Runbook via the SMA Management Portal, but am unable.  Windows gives no indication of what is wrong.

Whether I use the Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V, or the mouse, Windows refuses to paste content into the Runbook.  I've tried this on an existing Runbook and a few newly created Runbooks.

A coworker can do this with no issues.  Could this be a permission issue?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution is to add the portal to the list of Trusted Sites in IE.